# Using current application theme (NOT ACCENT)

Tags: themes, mahapps.metro, staticresource

I want to set the background of one of my controls based on the current THEME (BaseDark/BaseLight). Is this stored as a StaticResource anywhere? I've got my foreground set to `Foreground="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"` and I'd like an equivalent for the theme for my Background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Background="{DynamicResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
```

Spent a bunch of time just trying all the different brushes from the file until I arrived at this. Works perfectly.